# No Scroll bar on webpage I am building

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

As the title says I am having the issue of no scroll bar showing up on my web page. I have viewed similar questions to this one on stack overflow and I don't have some of the other common issues such as overflow: hidden. I thought it was a problem with bootstrap but I commented out all off the links to bootstrap CSS and I still dont get a scroll bar. I also added overflow: scroll to my CSS file and while a scroll bar showed up it still didnt work. My code is below and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    `<title>Cosmic Bowling!!!</title>`

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="bootstrap-3.3.2-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <link href="css/homepage.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>

  <div id="banner"></div>

  <table class="score-table" id="table1">
    <thead>

      <th>FR</th>
      <th>RD</th>
      <th>SCORE</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td class="_frameCol">1</td>
          <td class="_roundCol">
            <div class="big_div">
              <div class="_roll">
                <p>cat</p>
              </div>

              <div class="_roll">
                <p>cat</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td class="_scoreCol"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td class="_frameCol">2</td>
          <td class="_roundCol"></td>
          <td class="_scoreCol"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td class="_frameCol">3</td>
          <td class="_roundCol"></td>
          <td class="_scoreCol"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td class="_frameCol">4</td>
          <td class="_roundCol"></td>
          <td class="_scoreCol"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td class="_frameCol">5</td>
          <td class="_roundCol"></td>
          <td class="_scoreCol"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td class="_frameCol">6</td>
          <td class="_roundCol"></td>
          <td class="_scoreCol"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td class="_frameCol">7</td>
          <td class="_roundCol"></td>
          <td class="_scoreCol"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td class="_frameCol">8</td>
          <td class="_roundCol"></td>
          <td class="_scoreCol"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td class="_frameCol">9</td>
          <td class="_roundCol"></td>
          <td class="_scoreCol"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td class="_frameCol">10</td>
          <td class="_roundCol"></td>
          <td class="_scoreCol"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="bootstrap-3.3.2-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the CSS file

```
    body 
{
    background-image: url("images/stardust.png");
}

th
{
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

#banner
{
    /*position:fixed;*/
    background-image: url("images/bowling_banner.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
}

#table1
{
    /*positioning*/
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
}
.score-table,th,tr,td
{
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-width: 2px;
    color: white;

}

._frameCol
{
    text-align: center;

}

._roundCol
{
    height: 50px;
    width: 90px;
}

._scoreCol
{
    width: 10px;
}

._roll
{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: relative;

}

.big_div
{
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Sorry for the delay, here is the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ryyanj/us9undLf/

Comment: canyou replicate it in a code editor such as jsfiddle?

Comment: You don't have more contents, so you won't have the scrollbar, and if you want to show the scrollbar then you can use `overflow: scroll;`

Comment: yes I will replicate it right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to the table going off the bottom of the page...

This is because of the `#table1` CSS (in css/homepage.css), more specifically `position:fixed`

`position:fixed` is makes your element "float" - it is positioned relative to the browser window rather than the content. Because of this is won't expand the content so as to create scroll bars, even if it did you would be scrolling the **content**, not the window.

Since you didn't mention why the table was fixed I can only assume it's to space it 50% down the page, in which case your problem can be rectified by switching:

`position:fixed` to `position:absolute`

The CSS for `#table1` would then be:

```
#table1
{
    /*positioning*/
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much this worked perfectly and you explained the issue to me so I can avoid it in the future. I would upvote your answer but alas I have an extremely small reputation.

Comment: @user3233953 You're welcome, glad it fixed the problem. If you click the tick underneath the reputation buttons that will mark the answer as accepted (the answer that solved it).